# How do I disable the guest session from Lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, guest-session

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and one issue that I have with it is that there is no simple, easy way (as far as I know and please tell me if you have found a better way) to set up fool-proof parental controls. What I did with Ubuntu is to disable the guest account, password protect the admin account, and install ProCon Latte Content Filter on all the basic user’s firefox web browsers and configure them accordingly.

I got a new computer and decided to put Lubuntu 14.04 on it. Works great. Only issue so far: I cannot figure out how to disable the guest session. I searched around, but all the documentation tells me to sudo edit a file that doesn’t exist in Lubuntu 14.04. What does exist are these:

```
advanced@Dimension5150:/usr/lib/lightdm$ ls

guest-session-auto.sh  lightdm-greeter-session  lightdm-guest-session

advanced@Dimension5150:/etc/lightdm$ ls

lightdm.conf.d            lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu.conf
lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf  users.conf
```

So, could someone please tell me how to disable the guest session, or remove internet access (networking) from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html#disable) in the Ubuntu Desktop Guide. That solution works fine on Lubuntu too.

The instructions:

> If you prefer to not allow guest access to your computer, you can disable the Guest Session feature. To do so, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window, and then run this command (it's one long command, even if it may be shown wrapped on the screen - copy and paste to get it right):
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c 'printf "[SeatDefaults]\nallow-guest=false\n" >/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf'
> ```
>
> The command creates a small configuration file. To re-enable Guest Session, simply remove that file:
>
> ```
> sudo rm /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Add this line:

```
allow-guest=false
```

to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-lubuntu.conf`. Save the file and reboot.